# Writing numbers in group of 20s

Tags: c#, loops

I need help with this question:
Write a program that writes the numbers between 1 and 1000. The program will write the
numbers in groups of 20, asking the user whether or not he/she wants to continue visualizing the
next group of numbers.

So far I have this

```
        char a = ' ';

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}");

            if (i % 20 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue Y/N?: ");
                a = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (a == 'y')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

The problem is that it shows up like;
1..20, y/n, 20 22-40..

With the next group, it does show 20 numbers but it just starts with the number the last group ended with and it would skip the 1.. (21,41,61,etc).

Comment: The code inside `a == 'y'` is redundant. The loop will take care of that. All you need is `if (a != 'y') { break; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user enters `y`, you don't have to do anything, just let the program continue. In other cases, you could print an error or exit, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}");

    if (i % 20 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue Y/N?: ");
        a = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a != 'Y')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OK, Bye!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on the offending code:

```
if (a == 'y')
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}");
    i++;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

1. You've already printed `i` above this code, so there is no point printing it again. You'll just print it twice. So it will go 20 -> 20 -> 22.
2. `i++` works against you because the loop already takes care of that, so you end up incrementing `i` twice in one iteration. Because of this you'll actually be skipping a number here. Once you've fixed 1, it will go 20 -> 22, missing 21.
3. There is no early exit if the user doesn't input `y`.

So let's fix this. We only want to consider cases where the user doesn't want to continue, and we want to escape the loop in this case:

```
if (a != 'y')
{
    break; // break out of the loop
}
```

And putting it all together:

```
char a = ' ';

for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}");

    if (i % 20 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue Y/N?: ");
        a = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (a != 'y')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to output the number inside the "if"...

you don't need to increment the number inside the "if"...

all you need is the n case ... think of a break statement... it terminates the loop early